# How to add button for responsive table using ng prime

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Unable to get click functionality of button that is been displayed in responsive ngPrime table
Code as follows:-
HTML code

```
 <p-table #myTable [columns]="cols"
             [value]="results"
             [responsive]="true" >
        <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
            <tr>
                <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                    {{col.header}}
                </th>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
            <tr>
                <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                    <span class="ui-column-title">{{col.header}}</span>
                    <div>
                       {{rowData[col.field]}}
                    </div>                  
                    <div *ngIf="col.header === 'Click Me' ">
                        <button
                            pButton
                            type="button"
                            (click)="showPopup(result.id)"
                            label="Send"
                            class="ui-button-info"
                        ></button>                       
                    </div>                  
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>     
    </p-table>
```

TS code

```
 cols: any[];
 initColumns() {
        this.cols = [
            {field: 'id', header: 'Serial No'},
            {field: 'name', header: 'Name'},
            {field: 'status', header: 'Status'},
            {field: 'showPopup', header: 'Click Me'},
           
        ];
    }
```

The method initColumns I am calling in constructor.THe table I need is responsive, so used cols. All values are dynamic coming from results.  Only not able to get click functionality of Click Me button. Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. Every help is appreciated.

Comment: `result` is undefined according to the error message. What is `result`? You maybe mean `rowData.id`

Comment: your click event if firing just fine, the issue is with result which is undefined, double check if you missed somthing

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm results is array when I get data from backend service I am pushing the response in this results array.

Comment: @Elmehdi  No  , if result is undefined  then  how  other td data is getting displayed.

Comment: @Steve The other data is displayed by `results` in p-table's value (note the s in result**s**). Within the template each entry of `results` array is `rowData`. `result`(without s) is neither.

Comment: @Steave it think data is displayed using [value]="results"

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm yes, thanks. I got it I  had not taken variable as let proformaInvoiceLog.